# I need a way to briefly prevent my mouse from switching between screens

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

So my multi-monitor setup looks like this:

[image: Monitor Setup]

My problem is that my primary is the one in the centre and it's quite annoying when dealing with browser tabs as the mouse often goes to the above monitor and causes me to click things on the task bar up there.

I've found some old apps that provide a slight delay before allowing passage between monitors, but the only one that worked didn't support 4 monitors.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you considered moving the task bar on monitor4, so it's not at the bottom?

Comment: Oh my god, I didn't know you could move taskbars on a per-screen basis. That's nuts.

Comment: Although I dont' have 4monitor to test, but I have dual monitor. I was able to drag the task bar on one of the screen, so it's bottom for primary, and left on secondary. I hope that's a good workaround for you to avoid clicking on the wrong thing. Though, moving the monitor slightly off might help too

Answer (score 0):

Consider: tell Windows that monitor #4 is to the right of monitor #2.  Even if that isn't true.  It means you can't have a window overlap (top half on monitor 4 and bottom half on monitor 1), which you probably aren't doing anyways if you have a task bar on the bottom of monitor #4.  There may be other disadvantages as well, but I mention it as a consideration because it probably WILL be an easily implementable approach that directly helps with the specific struggle you're dealing with.